# Itextsharp: Error when converting directly from PdfReader to XMLDocument using ConvertToXML

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, itext

I'm writing a method to convert files and/or PdfReader to a XMLDocument

When I try with a file, it works perfectly.
However, I called the method using a PdfReader as a parameter and when passing through '**reader.ConvertToXml(pdfReader, ms);**' it throws out the error "Already closed". Any ideas

```
public static XmlDocument PDF_Tag_Extract(string filesource)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filesource);
    return PDF_Tag_Extract(pdfReader);
}

public static XmlDocument PDF_Tag_Extract(PdfReader pdfReader)
{

    TaggedPdfReaderTool reader = new TaggedPdfReaderTool();
    XmlDocument XMLized_PDF = new XmlDocument();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        reader.ConvertToXml(pdfReader, ms);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in ms.ToArray())
        {
            sb.Append((char)b);
        }
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
        var emptyElements = from descendant in doc.Descendants()
                            where descendant.IsEmpty || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(descendant.Value)
                            select descendant;
        emptyElements.Remove();
        XMLized_PDF.LoadXml(doc.ToString());
    }
    return XMLized_PDF;
}
```

Actually, this is the code where I call the method from:

```
public static void Process_Trademarks(string filesource)
{

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filesource);
    string[] PDF_TXT_page = new string[pdfReader.NumberOfPages];
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        // Separa la página en un nuevo PdfReader
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, output);
        copy.SetTagged();
        copy.CloseStream = false;
        document.Open();
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i, true));
        document.Close();
        PdfReader page = new PdfReader(output.ToArray());
        output.Close();
        copy.Close();

        // Página a XML
        try
        {
            // Identifies Section
            PDF_TXT_page[i - 1] = Common.ExtractText(page);
            // HERE IT ENTERS THE TROUBLESOME CODE.
            var xmlnodes = Common.PDF_Tag_Extract(page).DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Sect/Table");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However, I have found that if a put "PDF_TXT_page[i - 1] = Common.ExtractText(page);" after the "var xmlnodes = Common.PDF_Tag_Extract(page).DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Sect/Table");", the code works without problems.

Comment: I tried your code using both methods without an exception, can you post how you are calling it? `var x = PDF_Tag_Extract(testFile);var y = PDF_Tag_Extract(new PdfReader(testFile));`

Comment: Answered below is the code.

Comment: Based on your other comment I'm pretty sure that something in `Common.ExtractText(page)` is closing the stream.

Comment: Thanks, I will inquire what's going on there.